# Como saber quantos números existem de x até y?

Tags: algoritmo, matemática

Por exemplo de 0 até 60.
Obviamente eu sei quantos números existem, mas o que eu é saber como fazer o meu algoritmo descobrir isso matemáticamente.

Comment: `numero maior -  numero menor =  total de numeros entre eles`

Comment: Faça um `for` que totaliza/conta as iterações. Em números positivos fica muito evidente que o último é número total mas em números negativos ... por exemplo quantos números tem de `-3` até `0`?

Comment: @rray eu acho um laço muito *overkill* para o problema.

Comment: Olá David. Podes clarificar a pergunta e incluir um exemplo onde não consigas escrever código para resolver, e também a lingua de programação que usas.

Comment: Overkill é uma banda estado-unidense de thrash metal formada em 1980 na cidade de Nova Jersey e no comentario do Renam o que significa?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo muito trabalho/esforço para pouco resultado em outras palavras o custo é muito alto. Aí vc fica sem café e da esse tipo de sugestão haha xD ... epic fail...

Comment: @rray em qq caso direrente de uma simples operação matematica  é muito trabalho/esforço

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim, se quiser tirar a dúvida pode fazer uma medição.

Comment: @rray não é o caso, o cliente é rico e disposto a pagar qq preço já que tinha em mãos algo bem barato e fundamental. Aliás a pergunta não fala em performance.

Answer (score 7):

```js
function quantosNumerosExistem(x, y) {
    return Math.abs(y - x) + 1;
}

document.write(
    " De 3 até 10: " + quantosNumerosExistem(3, 10) + "<br>" +
    " De 0 até 60: " + quantosNumerosExistem(0, 60) + "<br>" +
    " De -2 até 2: " + quantosNumerosExistem(-2, 2) + "<br>" +
    " De 0 até 0: " + quantosNumerosExistem(0, 0) + "<br>" +
    " De 0 até 1: " + quantosNumerosExistem(0, 1) + "<br>" +
    " De -10 até -8: " + quantosNumerosExistem(-10, -8)
);
```

Comment: Bota em `Math.abs` antes de `x` e `y` para o caso de `x = -90; y = -12;` caso contraria vai dar errado, `Math.abs(x)`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Feito.